# Select last row for a certain group

Tags: mysql, select, optimization, query-performance

I have two tables:

**Table `users`**

```
columns | type   | notes
--------|--------|-------
id      | bigint | PK
...     | ...    | ...
```

**Table `events`**

```
columns    | type    | notes
-----------|---------|------
id         | bigint  | PK
user_id    | bigint  | FK(`users`.`id`)
event_name | varchar | ...
...        | ...     | ...
```

**Example of Table `events`**

```
id | user_id | event_name | ...
---|---------|------------|-----
 1 |       1 | A          | ...
 2 |       1 | B          | ...
 3 |       2 | F          | ...
 4 |       3 | C          | ...
 5 |       1 | A          | ...
 6 |       2 | A          | ...
```

I want get the latest event of a user (e.g: `user_id` is `1`). So far, I found two solutions:

```
SELECT events.*
    FROM events
    WHERE events.id = (SELECT MAX(events.id) FROM events WHERE (events.user_id = 1));
```

and

```
SELECT events.*
    FROM events
    WHERE events.user_id = 1
    ORDER BY events.id DESC
    LIMIT 0, 1;
```

Which one is the better solution for this case? Or maybe, is there any better solution?

FYI, I use MySQL 5.6.19 and InnoDB is the db engine.

Comment: The second. It's simpler. Since `id` is the PK of the table, both will return only 1 row.

Comment: The only thing that bothers me is the "latest" which uses the `id` and not a `date` attribute of the table. What happens if I forgot an event and then add it today, an event that is two months old. It will get the highest `id` and show up as latest although there are actually other events, later.

Comment: In this case, I assumed that the `events` are submitted in order and `events.id` is auto-increment. So, the largest `id` is the latest `events`.

Answer (score -2):

There would be marginal difference if any between both the queries, however, the second query is much simpler, so if it were me, I would prefer the second one!

*Another* way to do this would be:

```
SELECT MAX(events.id), events.user_id, events.event_name
FROM events
WHERE events.user_id = 1
```

Oh, and if you want to get the results of all user collectively, this query would help:

```
SELECT MAX(events.id), events.user_id, events.event_name
FROM events
GROUP by events.user_id
```

The output would be something like:

```
-------------------------------------
MAX(events.id) | user_id | event_name
-------------------------------------
       5       |    1    |    A
       6       |    2    |    F
       4       |    3    |    C
```

Comment: The queries are not logically correct (and it's a pity that MySQL allows such queries.) If a user is related to many events, which event name do you think that will be returned by these queries? It has to be one of them but which?